# How to update Firefox with MDM and no admin

Tags: macos, firefox, administrator, mdm

I am trying to update Firefox on my school computer but I need an Admin password to do this.

My MacBook is a 13” M2 Pro that has the weird school app store called “Self Service” which only lets you reinstall and not update.

Does any have an idea how I should update Firefox?

Comment: I think you already have your answer: you can't.

Comment: Contact your school admins for assistance

Comment: Self Service should install the latest version of the available app should the school's MDM be configured to do so. If it doesn't, then either your school's MDM admins have deemed it unnecessary and restricted it deliberately, or misconfigured Self Service. You might want to express your concern to your school admins, indicating that you're worried about possible security problems with the release you're using, especially if the version available is relatively old.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your school uses Jamf Pro to manage its Macs. Have you tried using Self Service to reinstall Firefox and see if it gives you the latest version? Some Jamf admins don't immediately make the latest versions of software available right away. Sometimes it has taken me a few days. One work around you could try is to download Firefox and then place the app somewhere that is not the default Applications folder. Your own home folder may have an Applications folder. That said, it is really necessary to have the latest version? It seems like the Firefox devs release a new version weekly.

Comment: ive tried downloading it and it says dont have permission to open app

Comment: If you can’t side load the Firefox download to your downloads folder, then help from the school IT team is your only avenue, @MatthewDesmond - their reinstall is very intentional to require them to package the new version and keep you on the older one until that happens.